# DbSet.Local is empty aftering adding to it

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework. I wanted to query objects before calling `SaveChanges()`. I searched a bit and found that I should use `Dbset.Local`. But my query returns always null. Here is my code.

I add to context here:

```
DB.RFH_ComplexRequestPersons.Add(person);
```

And query it here:

```
var model = DB.RFH_ComplexRequestPersons.Local.Where(d => d.FKComplexRequestID == requestID);
```

By the way DB is my context.

Comment: You checked if in your database have data about the person that you put in?

Comment: Person has a foreign key to another object that it is added to context just like the same. I'm using Master/Detail tables.

Comment: I think if the problem is not yout mapping, if the "person" have not the foreign key that you want. Because your code like Ok

Comment: I assume that the added `person` had `FKComplexRequestID == requestID`?

Comment: Yes. It has. But the request which requestID I'm passing to FKComplexRequestID is added to the context without calling SaveChanges() method. In My case ComplexRequest is master and person is detail. I add ComplexRequest to the context but don't call SaveChanges(). After adding persons and submitting, I will call SaveChanges().

Comment: I found the answer. The first problem was that I had a dbcontext per controller. The second problem was that I had to set ComplexRequest.